# video/mp2t browser live streaming support

Tags: html5-video, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts, iptv

Is there any way we could live stream "video/mp2t" content in the browser? I'm building a live stream app where some urls don't have any mimetype specified but the content is "video/mp2t". I've tried to use the major html 5 players: jwplayer, shaka-player, video.js, and none of them seem to support this kind of content out of the box. I've read that might be possible to transmux on the fly to mp4, do you guys know any example or some guidelines?

Android and ios seem to support this but the browser not, why is that? Do you think it's something to be incorporated in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that might be possible to transmux on the fly to mp4

Yes, you can write the code yourself, or base it on a another library like mux.js. But as you said, nothing does this out of the box.

> Android and ios seem to support this but the browser not, why is that?

There are dozens or hundreds of container formats. Supporting them all would be ridiculous. Different companies, and different standard bodies make different decisions on what they think their users will require.

> Do you think it's something to be incorporated in the future?

No, I don't.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it ? I am in the same situation, natively Android can do it but for iPhone it’s impossible with Safari.